# Angular Chart.js is not working with $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using [angular chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for populating a pie chart. For populating the chart I need to make a `$http.get()` call in service and call the service method from controller. But the chart is not working if I make `$http` call.

```js
angular.module('shopAdminApp')
.service('ChartService', ['$http',ChartService])

function ChartService($http) {

    this.GetAllChartData = function (month, year) {
        return $http.get('GetMonthlyStatistics?month=' + month + '&&year=' + year + '');
    }
}

angular.module('shopAdminApp')
.controller('chartCtrl', ["ChartService", ChartCtrl]);


function ChartCtrl(ChartService) {
   // this.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
   // this.data = [10, 20, 100];
    
    var promise = ChartService.GetAllChartData(12, 2012);
    promise.then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.chartsdata = response.data;
        this.labels = response.data.BranchNames;
        this.data = response.data.BranchMonthlyTotalSales;
    });
   
  //  console.log(this.chartsdata);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="pie1" class="chart chart-pie" data="chart.data" labels="chart.labels" height="300" width="400"></canvas>
```

If I un-comment the commented part, the pie chart works fine but I need to populate the value with `$http` call. How can I do that?

Comment: but you have `GetMonthlyStatistics?month=` which is not a url...

Comment: it is a url as I am using .net mvc with angular js.. and response.data.BranchNames returning the exact array that I commented for labels and response.data.BranchMonthlyTotalSale returning the exact value that I commented for data. I saw it using console.log. so no issue there.

Comment: Are you sure that the response from the server is ok? Why are you not using a rejection handler function as the second param function on your promise's `then`?

Comment: yeah 100% sure. No problem there. I checked the value of data and labels in fulfilled handler and they are ok. but the chart does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sth like this:

```
function ChartCtrl(ChartService) {
    var self = this;

    var promise = ChartService.GetAllChartData(12, 2012);
    promise.then(function (response) {
        self.chartsdata = response.data;
        self.labels = response.data.BranchNames;
        self.data = response.data.BranchMonthlyTotalSales;
    });
}
```

you have to remember that `this` keyword refer to current context, so when you're in promise callback function `this` no longer points to your controller, but to callback function itself.